# How do I use a TLFTextField in Flash Builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I've tried using a TLFTextField object in Flash Builder, instantiating it with code, but for some reason, Flash builder won't recognize the fl.text namespace, and won't import anything from fl.* or flashx.*

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the TLF runtime library into your project. It's located here:

`[Flash Application Directory]/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/tlfRuntime.swc`

I would copy that SWC to your project directory (under your `libs` folder if you have one) and then point to it in the *ActionScript Build Path* section under *Library Path* in your project properties.

Once you do that, the `fl.text.TLFTextField` class will be available to you in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from tlfRuntime.swc you might also want to include "textLayout.swc" which contains vital classes for the TLFTextField.

In CC support for TLFTextfield was dropped. You might need to install Flash Professional CS6 to find the above mentioned SWCs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the project properties/compiler options that you are targeting Flash 10 or higher. If you target a lower version of Flash the IDE won't include the TLF classes.